# How to fix Solr serach result distortion in almost same queries?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

Here is my Solr field type

---

```
<fieldType name="company_name" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
          <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

---

If I need to find documents in which field company_name is equal to "Abibas Sports", queries `fq=company_name:Abibas Sport` and `fq=company_name:Abibas Sports` return completely different results.  The most suitable case is `fq=company_name:Abibas Sport`.

How can I fix problem with character **s** at the end of the word.  Results must be same in each case.

---

First query:

[image: first query result]

---

Second query:

[image: second query result]

Answer (score 0):

Try by using `solr.PorterStemFilterFactory`

Porter stemmer is for the English language.

Its a normalization process that removes common endings from words.

```
Example: "riding", "rides", "horses" ==> "ride", "ride", "hors".
```

In your case `Sports` will `Sport`

Comment: Thank's! However in my case field is not only for English. if I declare olr.PorterStemFilterFactory, has it impact on quary with different languages?

Comment: It may be...But then in this whatever result you are getting are correct then...because this the way you are indexing the text and you will get the result based on your indexing(rather tokens created at the end of indexing...)

Comment: Or the other option is create those many fields as many languages are supported and apply the language specific stemmer if available...